# What makes mint feel painful?

Tags: pain, taste, senses, spearmint

By what mechanism does mint create a sensation similar to coldness or pain in one's mouth?  Why would this sensation become less and less over time with repeated exposure to mint?

Comment: I recommended an edit that conforms to site standards  It still may belong on BiologySE instead as it's more of a mechanisms question, it's a fine line.

Comment: Edited to conform to site standards for questions not related to an individual's health; please revert if disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone sees this for whatever reason (I guess if you look up this question...), the pain has gone away after me forcing myself to use mint toothpaste and other mint products.